# Does Apple Home support power metering in a plug or similar device?

Tags: homekit

I want to monitor the energy usage of a medical device and - if possible - trigger actions if it is turned off by itself.

I would like to use an Apple Home-compatible device (probably a plug) for this, for easy integration with what I have already.  A few years back I was told that the Apple Home-API's did not support power metering.

Has this changed and is there any suitable Home-compatible devices that can do this without non-Apple app support?

Comment: The problem you have is that turning the mains off will stop any device reporting. There are devices (Eve Energy) that report useage to their own app but not to Apple's app.

Comment: @mmmmmm turning off the device itself, not on the wall. The plug will not be unpowered.

Comment: Ok I think Eve Energy can do what you want - its app allows more complex rules than Apples - you can create a trigger on some chnages of power I think

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, the Apple Home app does not support power / energy metering at all. Behind the scenes, HomeKit will allow passing vendor proprietary data along - but it is not exposed in Apple's apps.

For example if you buy the Eve Energy product, you can add it to the Apple Home app and use that to turn the power on/off. However, you cannot monitor power usage. For that you'll need to use the third party app.

The only solution for using the Apple Home app is to add a special "bridge" to your setup. You can use an always-powered computer (desktop, laptop or something like a Raspberry Pi, Hoobs Pro or similar) to run open-source software such as [Homebridge](https://homebridge.io) that will allow you to create virtual HomeKit devices. From there you can define a virtual event to let the Apple Home app know that the device was turned off (i.e. power usage went to zero) - and then you can define rules on what to do with that information from the Apple Home app.